# Javascript - Using a variable to get a piece of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, cgi

I currently am working on a webpage that connects to a CGI backend.  The CGI backend so far works perfectly, but I don't know JavaScript that well, so I am struggling to handle getting the results from the AJAX JSON requests.

What I have:

A JavaScript function queries the CGI.

The CGI responds in a JSON array.

```
    {
    "ARRAY": [
        {
            "line": "1",
            "numbers": "12321",
            "var": "12321",
            "var2": "12321"
        },
        {
            "line": "2",
            "numbers": "-1",
            "var": "12320",
            "var2": "6160"
        }
    ]
}
```

line, numbers, var, and var2 must all be placed in separate cells of a table.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>line</th><th>numbers</th><th>var</th><th>var2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ARRAY[0].line</td><td>ARRAY[0].numbers</td><td>ARRAY[0].var</td><td>ARRAY[0].var2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ARRAY[1].line</td><td>ARRAY[1].numbers</td><td>ARRAY[1].var</td><td>ARRAY[1].var2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So, here is my problem:

I never know how many Objects are going to be inside the array.  Here there are 2, but sometimes there could be 20.  I can modify my JSON if needed.  How would I make it loop until it hits the last Object?

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways. The traditional one is to use a simple for loop:

```
for (var i = 0, len = ARRAY.length; i < len; i++) {
    //Build table row using ARRAY[i].line, etc
}
```

A while back we got Array.forEach, which as long as you don't have to support old versions of IE will work fine (you can also polyfill them):

```
ARRAY.forEach (function (idx, elt) {
    //Build table row using elt.line, etc
});
```

If you're using jQuery, there's also $.each:

```
$.each(ARRAY, function (idx, elt) {
    //Build table row using elt.line, etc
});
```

Here's a more complete example of what you need, using the jQuery library (not essential, but makes things easier):

```
var url = '/cgi-bin/your_script_name.cgi';
var html = '<table><tr><th>line</th><th>numbers</th><th>var</th><th>var2</th></tr>';
$.get(url, function (response) {
    $.each(response.ARRAY, function (idx, elt) {
        html += '<tr><td>' + elt.line + '</td><td>' + elt.numbers + '</td><td>' + elt.var + '</td><td>' + elt.var2 + '</td></tr>';
    });
    html += '</table>';
    $('#target-element').html(html);
});
```

In this example you're putting the table into an element with the id `target-element`, and your cgi script is located at `/cgi-bin/your_script_name.cgi`. If you can't use jQuery, you'll need to manually make the `XMLHttpRequest`, set its `responseType` to `'json'`, and bind a function to `onload` (or if supporting old browsers, `onreadystatechange` and then check for `readyState === 4`). Hope that helps.

Comment: and this will parse JSON?

Comment: Yes. And thanks for pointing out my flaw using for..in, Nathan. I just spent some time reading about the differences (which I had assumed there was none) and also why you would assign the length of the array to a variable to improve performance.

Comment: @zggz12 — JSON is JavaScript Object Notation, which basically means that when you're working with JSON in JavaScript, it is just a regular object. So if you use e.g. `jQuery.get()`, there's no parsing necessary. You just interact with the data like any other JavaScript object and you're good to go. @Trendy — Glad I could help :)

Comment: JSON itself is an ordinary string (Object _Notation_), not an object. So if you are in vanilla JavaScript then you first need to convert the JSON _string_ into a JS object using `JSON.parse()` (or `eval()` in older browsers). So your first 3 examples won't work as is. However, jQuery's `get()` automatically parses the response (JSON string to JavaScript object) providing the response is sent with the correct headers.

Comment: @w3d — Yes, I was perhaps oversimplifying. The question was 'how to loop over an array', so I figured going into detail about JSON parsing wasn't likely to help.